# Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to display the code in android studio and got this error:
Exception raised during rendering: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout.

I tried changing the code in many spots but nothing seemed to help.....
In the layout i was trying to make a line of text boxes and two parallel lines of TextView. I would like to keep this design so that it stays that way. so if someone has an answer that keeps it in place and fixes the problem i would be very great-full if he posted it.

this is my code:

```
<TextView
    android:text="@string/added"
    android:textSize="45sp"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_name4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_name4"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView7" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView9" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView13" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView14"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView13" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView15"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView16"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cb11"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/cb11" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView17"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView18" 
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView15"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView15"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView18"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView38"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView17"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView17" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView19"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView20"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView19" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView21"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView22"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView21" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView43"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView24"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView24" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView24"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView22" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView25"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/welcome_name4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/welcome_name4" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView26"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView28"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView27"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView28"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView29"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView30"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView31"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView32"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView34"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView35"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView34"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView36"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView35"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView37"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView36"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView38"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView37"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView39"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView38"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/welcome_name4"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/welcome_name4" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView40"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView41"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView40"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView42"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView41"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView43"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView42"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/textView44"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView43"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" android:textColor="#000"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb1"
    android:tag="1"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_name4" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb2"
    android:tag="2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="3"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView8" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="4"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cb3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView8" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="5"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView10" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="6"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb6"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cb5"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView11" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="7"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView11" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:tag="8"
    android:id="@+id/cb8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView13"
    android:checked="false" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="9"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView14" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="10"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView14" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="11"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cb10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView16" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="12"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cb11"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView17" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="13"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView17" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="14"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb14"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView19" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="15"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView20" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="16"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb16"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView21" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="17"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb17"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView20"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView22" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="18"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb18"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView21"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView22" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="19"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb19"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView22"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView23" />

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:tag="20"
    android:onClick="deleteMember"
    android:id="@+id/cb20"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView44" />
```

Thanks a lot for helping:)

Comment: You should probably look into a ListView or RecyclerView...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Views are referring to each other in a bidirectional way, which causes the circular dependency that you should not have. 
For example: textView5's position in the layout is based on textView6's position, but textView6's position is also based on textView5's position. This dependency should be only one-way.

Comment: This is the correct answer, fix those Textviews and it should be working